# ASP.NET web forms change bootstrap theme dynamicly

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bootstrapping

my main problem is that I want to change the bootstrap theme of my Website with a Dropdown list of themes and a button.

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjectManagementTool.ServiceReference1.Theme>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Settings";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<form action="/Home/Settings" method="get">

    <h2>Settings</h2>
    <br />

    <h4>Change Theme</h4>
    @Html.DropDownList("GetThemes", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
    <br />
    <p>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </p>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Path)
    <br/>
}


</form>
```

The foreach loop is just to show the diffrent paths.

I have a database aswell with a themes table:
[image]

Now the question is, how can I change the bootstrap?

I know that there is this code tho change the theme.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/flatly.bootstrap.css")
```

But it should be in the _layout.cshtml file to set it for the whole website.

The background is working with a service but this is not important here.

Screenshot of the website:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could write an action that returns the path of the css file to be used depending on the user settings.

Something along the lines of

```
@Styles.Render(Html.Action("UserCssPath", "Settings").ToString());
```

Because you don't have access to a ViewModel in your layout page, the controller must use another mechanism to find out for which user the action was invoked. For example, we store a User Context object with the required data in the `HttpContext.Current.Session`. This could be written once on logon. The UserCssPath action can then access the DB to find the correct CSS path and return it: `return Content(cssPath);`